# Triple boot Windows Vista, Ubuntu 11.10, Kubuntu 11.10

Tags: kubuntu, dual-boot, windows-vista

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 from Windows Vista using Wubi, on my secondary hard drive.
I want to install Kubuntu 11.10 in addition to Windows and Ubuntu on this secondary hard drive. It has 1 partition in NTFS . I've already prepared a live USB key with Kubuntu on it. What should I do now?

Comment: dual boot. Ubuntu inside Vista with wubi does not count as a boot option ;)

Answer (score 1):

By default wubi will remove the existing install prior to installing the second.

The best you can do is to install Kubuntu inside your Ubuntu and then choose at login which to use.

If you find there is not enough room it is possible to increase the size of the wubi disk - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_resize_the_virtual_disks.3F

Search for kubuntu-desktop in Software Centre or if you wish to do so from a terminal the command is

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

You will end up with multiple entries in your menus.

If you wish to then remove kubuntu you can find details here - make sure to use correct version

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnome

Wubi Guide - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Answer (score 0):

> It has 1 partition in NTFS

Start with splitting this into 2 partitions: 1 with Windows, 1 empty formatted to `ext4` or `ext3` instead of NTFS. You can use partition magic for this if you need the windows version (though it is not free ;) ) or use the Live USB you created. More info on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/92287/how-do-i-split-the-system-partition-c-in-windows7-without-creating-a-dynamic). On [sevenforums](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/22723-hard-drive-partitions-changing-gparted.html) there is a big Windows 7 + Gparted guide with lots of images that can help you (that will work for Vista too).

After that you can install either kUbuntu (KDE) or Ubuntu (Gnome/Unity) on this new partition.

You will end up with actually 2 operating systems installed (and not a wubi install) and you will get a prompt at boottime to choose what system to start. You can still use Ubuntu from within Windows with the WUBI install.